# Ask, how to delete all data on sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to make "clear-all" button which delete all data in my sqlite, my code is like this :

```
private void clearAll() {

        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        notesCursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
        for(int i=0;i<notesCursor.getCount();i++){
            mDbHelper.deleteNote(i);
        }
        }while(notesCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

but i can't delete it, anyone can help me to solve this problem? thanks before

Comment: We need to see the method `delete()` of your helper to see what happens. But anyway, rather than doing `i` times `DELETE FROM your_table WHERE ID=i`, you should just do `DELETE FROM your_table` if the purpose is to delete all entries

Comment: there's only 2 method when i typed delete, it is deleteDatabase and deletefile, hmmmm, am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to use something like this:

```
mDbHelper.delete("tableName",null,null);
notesCursor.requery();
```

To delete all the values in your table and update your cursor.

Comment: delete methode on my code is only mdbhelper.deletenote(rowID), nothing else, i wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're getting the count of your "notes" table in order to pass in to use as the ID for the delete statement.  Why?   How can you guarantee that the IDs will match up?  This is especially true after subsequent deletes.   Why not just call the SQLiteDatabase delete() method without a specific ID to delete all the records?

Comment: hmmm, that's make sense, but the delete method on my code is mdbhelper.deletenote(rowID) nothing else, am i missing something?

Comment: yes - and what i'm saying is that rowID isn't really an ID because you're getting it from the iteration of a getCount() method.  Do you understand what I'm saying?   Also, post the code from the deletenote() method.

Comment: yes, i'm understand, i've changed the code, well, there is no deletenote() method, when i typed mdbhelper. and press ctrl+space, it is already there...

Comment: post your solution in case someone with the same problem finds this.